# Why are we (humans) more likely to help people genetically related to us than people who are not?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, anthropology

> **Question.** Why are we (humans) more likely to help people genetically related to us than people who are not?

My understanding of this question as follows:

Because the reproduction of people genetically related to us can help us spread our genes. People genetically related to us are also more likely to help ourselves to reproduce.

Is this correct? What am I missing?

I was wondering if anybody had anything, especially intuition or some finer nuances, to add to what I have to say.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back up your claim?

Comment: Is it a homework question?

Comment: Why was this question closed? The idea that humans tend to be altruistic toward genetically related individuals is not outlandish.

Comment: This question seems to fall under the field of sociobiology, and more specifically I think kin selection. It's a controversial topic.  If sociobiology is a subfield of biology then it shouldn't have been closed. On the other hand if sociobiology is more of a social science, then I guess it should be asked somewhere else.  Still, it's a very interesting question.

Comment: I heard something like this before. E.g. it's important that children look like their parents because if they don't the mother probably cheated on the father. Promiscuous partners increase the chance of catching a disease, and so evolution made monogamous couples more prone to procreating which also helps to root the behaviour. Furthermore humans are social beings and like other primates, we strive together, so our relationships are very important. So much so that we even developed language.

Comment: I don't have time to search articles and I was just summing up related anthropological information I came across at some point. But I find your thesis very plausible. Like I said primates are social beings and of course we'll spend more time with family through out our lives, thereby building stronger bonds with genetically related individuals that help us survive as a group. Lots of other species of mammals do that too to some extent: lions and wolves.

Comment: It's also a no-brainer that the parents of any living offspring that take better care of their offspring will end up delivering offspring that will survive and succeed more often which is pretty much what you said. More advantages can be drawn from extending this model to less genetically related individuals such as cousins, the culmination of it all being an Italian mafia. :P